# In the real world, what is the stream function $Ψ$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, potential, vector-fields, complex-numbers

So I know that complex potential is just $Ω=Φ+iΨ$

$Φ$ is the potential function which associates a scalar value to every point on the field. Lines where $Φ$ is constant are the equipotential lines. In the real world, the scalar values to each point are temperature values at every point in a map while the equipotential lines are the isotherms.

How about for the [stream function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function) $Ψ$. The stream function also assigns a scalar value to every point on the field and the lines with the same scalar values are the streamlines. In the real world, these streamlines can be the wind vectors right? But what do the scalar values assigned by the stream function actually mean?

Comment: Differences in the stream function are proportional to the amount of fluid flowing between the streamlines.